# useMemo in react with promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have API call that I do not want to repeat when user is going from tab to tab inside react app (I am fine with repeating it if the user refreshes the page completely)

This is what I have inside React Component:

```
const banksPromise = useMemo(() => loadCard(), []);

async function loadCard() {
  const banks = await getBankInfo(token);
  return banks;
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function execute() {
    const banks = await banksPromise;
    setState({banks});
  }

  execute();
},[]);
```

But when I go to other React tab and back (the browser itself is not refreshed, its all part of single react app) the loadCard function is executed again. I would be expecting the memo should memorized it.

Altough its async function and returns a promise - the promise itself should remain the same and when you "await" it after its resolved, it should just return the value.

bonus question: can I use useEffect in a better way with promises/async functions? If I just make the function inside useEffect `async` I get an error as then it returns the promise and useEffect expect a function (so I did this workaround)

Comment: As for your tab switch case, I think when your component is dismounted, all states inside your component will be cleaned up, and when your component is mounted again, it will trigger whole state cycles again including `useMemo`. Therefore, `useMemo` here does not matter. If you want to achieve this "cached" data, you should move your API call to the parent component where is shared among tab components (but it's not ideal though). Or you can use some caching techniques from libraries like useSWR or React Query.

Comment: @NickVu - ah, then I probably misunderstood the definition. I thought the "useMemo is a React Hook that lets you cache the result of a calculation between re-renders." means it caches it when I go through the app - but obviously it is not like that.